# How do I know when DOM “body” element is available?

Tags: javascript, events, dom, onload

As soon as `body` DOM node is available, I'd like to add a class to it with JavaScript.
I want this to happen *as soon as possible*, before any of `body`'s children are loaded.

Right now, I'm using an inline script right after opening `body` tag. Is there a less obtrusive way?

Comment: body.onload = function () { ... } ?

Comment: Does body.onload event wait for the children to be loaded too?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @qwertymk To `hide` the page and then show it once everything, including images, have loaded.

Comment: @Oddant see mini-disproof: http://jsfiddle.net/paislee/aVXkh/

Comment: @Xander: You can append `<style>body { display: none; }</style>` with `js` then. Is that the only possible reason for this?

Comment: @qwertymk: A page has several tabs that depend on `location.hash`. By reading `location.hash` in the very beginning and setting corresponding styles, I'm able to instantly show only current tab elements.

Comment: @qwertymk And in fact you just made me realize that I can set these styles on `html` as well. This way I can just put it in my JS initialization code in `head`. Thanks for the clue :-)

Comment: @Xander: Some apps are not supposed to work without JS anyway (think of an API consumer).

Comment: @DanAbramov Is that what you're developing? A `JS` API?

Comment: @Xander: A simple page that talks a lot with a specific website's API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would imagine this will differ between browsers.

One solution may be to test for it by placing a script immediately inside the opening `<body>` tag, then running your code at an interval to add the class.

```
<body>
    <script>
    function add_class() { 
        if(document.body)
             document.body.className = 'some_class';
        else 
            setTimeout(add_class, 10);  // keep trying until body is available
    }
    add_class();
    </script>

    <!-- rest of your elements-->
</body>
```

jQuery does something similar internally ***to deal with a particular IE bug***.

There isn't a guarantee that the descendant elements won't be loaded though, since again it will depend on when the particular implementation makes the `body` available.

---

***[Here's the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.1/src/core.js#L400-403)*** where jQuery takes a similar approach, testing for the existence of the `body` in its main `jQuery.ready` handler, and repeatedly invoking `jQuery.ready` via `setTimeout` if the `body` isn't available.

And [here's an example](http://jsbin.com/azakal/edit#preview) to see if your browser can see the `<body>` element in a script at the top of the element, before the other elements. *(Open your console)*

*[Here's the same example](http://jsbin.com/azakal/4/edit#preview) without needing the console.*

Comment: jQuery does not do any similiar at all.

Comment: @jAndy: Yes it does, in a specific case to get around an IE bug where it shows the DOM ready without the `body` actually being available.

Comment: @jAndy: [Here's the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.1/src/core.js#L401-403)

Comment: no it doesn't. It uses a `try-catch` statement where it calls `document.documentElement.doScroll("left");` periodly. Slight difference.

Comment: well, that is not the actually work-around code for the missing `DOMContentLoaded` event in IE. Its just an on-top check.

Comment: @jAndy: Yes, that's all I meant. I didn't mean that it was the actual DOM-ready approach. Just a workaround for an IE bug.

Answer (score 6):

Might be a bit late to the party but...

You can just tap into the browser rendering cycle. Thus you don't have to deal with timeouts which leak memory (if improperly used).

```
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = '//localhost:4000/app.js';
  (function appendScript() {
    if (document.body) return document.body.appendChild(script);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(appendScript);
  })();
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. But I had issues with something in this early state. For example the mutations of the MutationObserver does no follow all subtrees, even when specified